# SQL Send an email based on Query Results, only if query returns results

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I have a Table with fields like Order and Ship By Date. 
I can create a query that shows me all my Orders and their Ship By date. 
Then I can modify it to only show me Orders that need to be shipped within 24 Hours. 
I want to create an email blast that contains all those 24 hour orders. However, if there are no orders that need to be shipped out, I don't want it to send an empty email, I want it to send nothing at all.

I know how to create a subscription through SSRS.

BTW, if we have the ability to send subscriptions through SSRS, does that mean we have a Database Mail Profile set up? So would I be able to use some code like this?

```
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'your mail profile',
    @recipients = 'dba@company.com',
    @body = 'results -- some body goes here',
    @subject = 'Sensible subject goes here ',
-- to send file attachments (if any)
    @file_attachments = 'L:\logs.TXT',
  -- send query results 
    @query = 'Select Cast(case when count(inventory.items) > 1000 then 1 else 0 End as bit) as SendAlert
From Inventory';
```

How do I find out what my profile_name is? I tried going to Management > Database Mail and sending a test email but it didn't work.

If that means I don't have a profile set up, I'm assuming I'm going to have to do this through a Data Driven Subscription? Maybe would I left join the email address I am trying to send to the query and send to that fields email? That way if there are no results, no emails will get sent out. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:
 1. Use a variable to pass the COUNT of Orders that need to be shipped within 24 Hours. DECLARE @NumOrders INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.schema.table WHERE date <=24 hrs (date diff/dateadd works here)
 2. Now:

```
IF @NumOrders > 0
BEGIN
    Write a cursor to get all orders and emails.... <= 24hrs
    Send email
END
```